# TypeError: obj is not defined erro de acesso e uma array

Tags: javascript, html5

Quando tento rodar o seguinte código

```js
 var largura = 800,
 altura = 500,
 mainColor,canvas,ctx,

 player = {
  x:400,
  y:250,
  largura:50,
  altura:50,
  color:"#cc3030"
 },

 obstaculo = {
  obstaculos:[],
  time:0,
  insert:function(){
   this.obstaculos.push({
    color:"#3030cc",
    altura:20+Math.floor((Math.random()*51)),
    largura:40+Math.floor((Math.random()*41)),
    y:0-this.altura,
    x:Math.floor((Math.random()*largura-this.largura)),
    grav:1.5,
    velocity:0});
  },

  update:function(){
   if (this.time <= 0) {
    obstaculo.insert();
    this.time = 10+Math.random()*21;
   } else {
    this.time--;
   }

   for (var i = 0;i <= this.obstaculos.length; i++) {
    var obj = this.obstaculos[i];
    obj.velocity += obj.grav;
    obj.y += obj.velocity;
   }

   obstaculo.draw();
  },

  draw:function(){
   for (var i = 0;i < this.obstaculos.length; i++) {
    var obj = this.obstaculos[i];
    drawObject(obj.color,obj.x,obj.y,obj.altura,obj.largura);
    }
   }
  };

function main () {
 canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 canvas.height = altura;
 canvas.width = largura;
 canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 mainColor = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,altura);
 mainColor.addColorStop(0,"#aaa");
 mainColor.addColorStop(0.5,"#ccc"); 
 mainColor.addColorStop(1,"#aaa");

 update();
}

function update(){
 draw();
 drawObject(player);
 obstaculo.update();

 requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function draw(){
 ctx.fillStyle = mainColor;
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,largura,altura);
}

function drawObject (object) {
 ctx.fillStyle = object.color;
 ctx.fillRect(object.x,object.y,object.largura,object.altura);
}

function move (e){
 player.x = e.clientX-(player.largura/2);
 player.y = e.clientY-(player.altura/2);
}
```

```html
<body style="width: 800px;height: 500px;" onload="main()">

</body>
```

obtenho o erro `TypeError: obj is undefined` nas linhas 37,71,65 e 1; [ao que entendi](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_type) o erro ocorre quando o valor da variável esta indefinido, porém no meu ver o valor de obj esta definido, tanto que se eu digitar `obstaculo.obstaculos[0]` no console ele me retorna o objeto com os valores corretos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o teu problema é esta linha (que aparece duas vezes):

```
for (var i = 0;i <= this.obstaculos.length; i++) {
```

Não podes usar `<= array.length` a percorrer arrays, isto porque se a array tiver length 5, o numero do index é 4. Ou seja:

```
var arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

arr.length // 5
arr[4] // 50
arr[5] // undefined
```

Muda o código para `<` somente. Assim:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.obstaculos.length; i++) {
    var obj = this.obstaculos[i];
```

```js
var largura = 800,
  altura = 500,
  mainColor,
  canvas,
  ctx,
  player = {
    x: 400,
    y: 250,
    largura: 50,
    altura: 50,
    color: '#cc3030'
  },
  obstaculo = {
    obstaculos: [],
    time: 0,
    insert: function() {
      this.obstaculos.push({
        color: '#3030cc',
        altura: 20 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 51),
        largura: 40 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 41),
        y: 0 - this.altura,
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * largura - this.largura),
        grav: 1.5,
        velocity: 0
      });
    },

    update: function() {
      if (this.time <= 0) {
        obstaculo.insert();
        this.time = 10 + Math.random() * 21;
      } else {
        this.time--;
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < this.obstaculos.length; i++) {
        var obj = this.obstaculos[i];
        obj.velocity += obj.grav;
        obj.y += obj.velocity;
      }

      obstaculo.draw();
    },

    draw: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.obstaculos.length; i++) {
        var obj = this.obstaculos[i];
        drawObject(obj.color, obj.x, obj.y, obj.altura, obj.largura);
      }
    }
  };

function main() {
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  canvas.height = altura;
  canvas.width = largura;
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  mainColor = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, altura);
  mainColor.addColorStop(0, '#aaa');
  mainColor.addColorStop(0.5, '#ccc');
  mainColor.addColorStop(1, '#aaa');

  update();
}

function update() {
  draw();
  drawObject(player);
  obstaculo.update();

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = mainColor;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, largura, altura);
}

function drawObject(object) {
  ctx.fillStyle = object.color;
  ctx.fillRect(object.x, object.y, object.largura, object.altura);
}

function move(e) {
  player.x = e.clientX - player.largura / 2;
  player.y = e.clientY - player.altura / 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body style="width: 800px;height: 500px;" onload="main()">

</body>

</html>
```